# How can I update an ordinal property on a set of nodes in a single query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database with nodes representing containers, which are ordered by the property 'ordinal'. When one container is removed, I need to renumber the ordinal property of the remaining containers under a parent container.

The behaviour I want in a cypher query is, on deletion of child1, the ordinals for remaining children should be contiguous and retain the same order. In this case, child2's ordinal would become 1 to replace the removed child 1.

Of course, this is easy to achieve by fetching all children, delete the child you want, then iterate over the nodes updating the ordinal from the backend side. However, I would think there might be a way to do this in a single cypher query with a FOREACH, but can't quite figure out how.

```
CREATE (parent:Container {uid: 0, ordinal: 0})
CREATE (child0:Container {uid: 1, ordinal: 0})-[:IS_SUBCONTAINER_OF]->(parent)
CREATE (child1:Container {uid: 2, ordinal: 1})-[:IS_SUBCONTAINER_OF]->(parent)
CREATE (child2:Container {uid: 3, ordinal: 2})-[:IS_SUBCONTAINER_OF]->(parent)
```

Is this possible to achieve in a single cypher query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without `FOREACH`. This can be done with `OPTIONAL MATCH` (This also updates nodes at the backend side) as follows:

```
MATCH (child:Container)
WHERE child.uid=5   //Change this as per your requirements
OPTIONAL MATCH (child)-[:IS_SUBCONTAINER_OF]->()<-[:IS_SUBCONTAINER_OF]-(other_child:Container)
WHERE other_child.ordinal > child.ordinal
DETACH DELETE child
SET other_child.ordinal = other_child.ordinal-1
```

Comment: This decreases the ordinal value of all the childrens only if it is greater than the current node(node to delete).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.